# ASP.NET MVC Master Page Variable Scope

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, scope, master-pages

I don't understand the scope of the variables in my .Master pages - can anyone assist?

In the example below `settings` cannot be seen in either usage following its instantiation:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>

<% var settings = new SettingRepository(); %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <meta name="description" content="<%: settings.metaDescription %>"/>

    <title>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /> - <%: settings.pageTitle %>
    </title>

...
```

In the example below `settings` can only be seen in the FIRST usage, but not the second:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <% var settings = new SettingRepository(); %>
    <meta name="description" content="<%: settings.metaDescription %>"/>

    <title>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /> - <%: settings.pageTitle %>
    </title>

...
```

Comment: Would the downvoter mind explaining why he downvoted so I can fix my wrongdoing? :)

Answer (score 0):

According to me what ever variable you use in Master page it is accessible to its XAML file and cs file.

You can access it in its content pages like this:

```
String variable=((MasterPageName).this.Master).variable;
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. This requires that a property is defined in the code-behind, but the example never uses it (and shouldn't need to)

Answer (score 0):

Use @MasterType directive, as explained here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.aspx

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. We're already in the Master page, why do we need to define it again?